# Persian Characters in MPAndroidChart MarkerView

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I use MPAndroidChart in my app and create a custom MarkerView (CustomMarkerView) for charts.

when I use Persian characters in CustomMarkerView, the title shows empty.

```
@Override
public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {

    tvContent.setText("عنوان تستی: " + Utils.formatNumber(e.getVal(), 0, true));

}
```

any idea for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's a bug. I add an unicode character (\u200e) to the title and Persian characters show in title.

```
@Override

public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {

    tvContent.setText("\u200e"+"عنوان تستی: " + Utils.formatNumber(e.getVal(), 0, true));

}
```